# Unable to get an image to fit inside the bounds of a UITextField

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uitextfield

I'm trying to get the image to scale down to the size of the UITextField and to position itself to the left side of it, but I am only able to get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the relevant code:

```
//MARK: - Add Left Image to UITextField

func addLeftImageTo(txtField: UITextField, image img: UIImage) {
    let leftImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    leftImageView.image = img
    txtField.addSubview(leftImageView)
    txtField.leftView = leftImageView
    txtField.leftViewMode = .always
}

let image1 = UIImage(named: "stopwatch")

addLeftImageTo(txtField: timerTextField, image: image1!)

timerTextField.anchor(top: repsTextField.bottomAnchor, leading: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, bottom: notesTextField.topAnchor, trailing: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 50.adjusted, left: 100.adjusted, bottom: 50.adjusted, right: 100.adjusted))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the UIImageView in a UIView

**Your code:**

```
func addLeftImageTo(txtField: UITextField, image img: UIImage) {
        let leftImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        leftImageView.image = img
        txtField.addSubview(leftImageView)
        txtField.leftView = leftImageView
        txtField.leftViewMode = .always
    }
```

**Example:**

```
func addLeftImageTo(txtField: UITextField, image img: UIImage) {
    let height = txtField.frame.size.height
    let wrapView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: height, height: height))

    let leftImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: height, height: height))
    leftImageView.image = img
    leftImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    wrapView.addSubview(leftImageView)

    txtField.addSubview(wrapView)
    txtField.leftView = wrapView
    txtField.leftViewMode = .always
}
```

Also, I added some lines including **height**, **contentMode** just in case.

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your suggestion, but unfortunately this did not work for me. The image disappeared entirely when I tried to implement this code.

Comment: @RapsIn4 Can you try setting let height into 40 instead of txtField.frame.size.height?

Comment: Thanks pal, it worked! Changing the height did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

first make below method for adding image in `UITextField`

```
  func setleftPaddingInTextfieldwithImage(_ textfield : UITextField, padding : 
   CGFloat, strImgname : String)
   {

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: strImgname))
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15 , height: 15)

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        let paddingView = UIView.init()
        paddingView.frame = CGRect(x: padding, y: 0, width: padding, height: textfield.frame.size.height)

        paddingView.addSubview(imageView)
        textfield.leftView = paddingView
        textfield.leftViewMode = .always

   }
```

call it in your viewcontroller

```
 self.setleftPaddingInTextfieldwithImage(YourTextField, padding: padding, strImgname: "stopwatch")
```